# Intersection of files

Tags: algorithm, file, unix, intersection

I two large files (27k lines and 450k lines). They look sort of like:

```
File1:
1 2 A 5
3 2 B 7
6 3 C 8
...

File2:
4 2 C 5
7 2 B 7
6 8 B 8
7 7 F 9
...
```

I want the lines from both files in which the 3rd column is in both files (note lines with A and F were excluded):

```
OUTPUT:
3 2 B 7
6 3 C 8
4 2 C 5
7 2 B 7
6 8 B 8
```

whats the best way?

Comment: Simplest is to scan through once, extract the column, and calculate the intersections, then scan through again and extract the matching rows.

Comment: Are the matching fields single characters as in the example data?  Could you create a character class that would select the values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '{print $3}' file1 | sort | uniq > file1col3
awk '{print $3}' file2 | sort | uniq > file2col3
grep -Fx -f file1col3 file2col3 | awk '{print "\\w+ \\w+ " $1 " \\w+"}' > col3regexp
egrep -xh -f col3regexp file1 file2
```

Grabs all the unique column 3's in the two files, intersects them (using `grep -F`), prints a bunch of regular expressions that will match the columns you want, then uses `egrep` to extract them from the two files.

Comment: Thanks, i did almost EXACTLY the same thing!

Answer (score 3):

first we sort the files on the third field :

```
sort -k 3 file1 > file1.sorted
sort -k 3 file2 > file2.sorted
```

then we get common values on the 3rd field using comm :

```
comm -12 <(cut -d " " -f 3 file1.sorted | uniq) <(cut -d " " -f 3 file2.sorted | uniq) > common_values.field
```

now we can join each sorted file on the common values :

```
join -1 3 -o '1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4' file1.sorted common_values.field > file.joined
join -1 3 -o '1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4' file2.sorted common_values.field >> file.joined
```

output is formated so we get the same field order as the one used in the files.
Standard unix tools used : sort, comm, cut, uniq, join.
The `<( )` works with bash, for other shells you might use temp files instead.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an option using grep, sed and cut.

Extract column 3:

```
cut -d' ' -f3 file1 > f1c
cut -d' ' -f3 file2 > f2c
```

Find matching lines in `file1`:

```
grep -nFf f2c f1c | cut -d: -f1 | sed 's/$/p/' | sed -n -f - file1  > out
```

Find matching lines in `file2`:

```
grep -nFf f1c f2c | cut -d: -f1 | sed 's/$/p/' | sed -n -f - file2 >> out
```

Output:

```
3 2 B 7
6 3 C 8
4 2 C 5
7 2 B 7
6 8 B 8
```

#### Update

If you have asymmetric data files and the smaller one fits into memory, this one-pass awk solution would be pretty efficient:

*parse.awk*

```
FNR == NR {
  a[$3] = $0
  p[$3] = 1
  next
}  

a[$3]

p[$3] {
  print a[$3]
  delete p[$3]
}
```

Run it like this:

```
awk -f parse.awk file1 file2
```

Where `file1` is the smaller of the two.

*Explanation*

- The `FNR == NR` block reads `file1` into two hashes.
- `a[$3]` prints `file2` line if `$3` is a key in `a`.
- `p[$3]` prints `file1` line if `$3` is a key in `p` and deletes the key (only print once).

Answer (score 1):

First obtain the common values from the third column. Then filter the lines from both files that have a matching third column.

If the columns are delimited by a single character, you can use `cut` to extract one column. For columns that can be separated by an arbitrary amount of whitespace, use `awk`. One way to obtain the common column 3 values is to extract the columns, sort them and call [`comm`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=comm&sektion=1). Using bash/ksh/zsh process substitutions:

```
comm -12 <(awk '{print $3}' file1 | sort -u) <(awk '{print $3}' file2 | sort -u)
```

Now turn these into `grep` patterns, and filter.

```
comm -12 <(awk '{print $3}' file1 | sort -u) <(awk '{print $3}' file2 | sort -u) |
sed -e 's/[][.\|?*+^$]/\\&/g' \
    -e 's/.*/^[^[:space]]+[[:space]]+[^[:space]]+[[:space]]+\1[[:space]]/' |
grep -E -f - file1 file2
```

The method above should work reasonably well with huge files. But at 500k lines, you don't have huge files. Those files should fit comfortably in memory, and a simple Perl solution will be fine. Load both files, extract the columns values, print the matching columns.

```
perl -n -e '
    @lines += 1;
    $c = (split)[2];
    $seen{$c}{$ARGV} = 1;
END {
    foreach (@lines) {
        $c = (split)[2];
        print if %{$seen{$c}} == 2;
    }
}' file1 file2
```