# Intersection between two files

Tags: linux

I am a first-timer at programming, and I'm trying to find the intersection of two text files.

```
file1.txt
a a
a b
a a
a c

file2.txt
a a
```

I want to get the result below in `file1` (lines in `file2` that are in `file1`)

```
a a
a a
```

I try to use `grep` command in Linux but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: http://www.catonmat.net/blog/set-operations-in-unix-shell-simplified/

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12443110/intersection-of-files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw something similar here https://stackoverflow.com/a/36591385/4053813

```
< file1 xargs -I % grep -xF '%' file2
```

Edit: As pointed out by @Julien Lopez I added -xF options to grep command.

Comment: `-I string` option for `xargs` allows you to replace `string` by the input. So this answer does `grep 'inputline' file2` for every `inputline` in `file1`. You should add the `-x` option of `grep` to match the whole line (else you will match `a a d` for example), and this won't work if you have duplicates in `file2` since you are doing multiple `grep`s. As @Ziggy pointed out, you also want to use the `-F` option of `grep` to consider the input as strings and not regular expressions.

Answer (score 5):

Using `grep`:

`grep -xFf file2.txt file1.txt`

> ```
> -F, --fixed-strings
>           Interpret  PATTERN  as  a  list  of  fixed  strings (rather than
>           regular expressions), separated by newlines, any of which is  to
>           be matched.
> -f FILE, --file=FILE
>           Obtain patterns  from  FILE,  one  per  line.   The  empty  file
>           contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.
> -x, --line-regexp
>           Select only those matches that exactly  match  the  whole  line.
>           This option has the same effect as anchoring the expression with
>           ^ and $.
> ```

Comment: Note that grep, even used this way, will compare a list of patterns, not text, so if file2.txt includes characters that are regex commands or wildcards (such as *), it will not work as expected. A solution is to escape all lines in file2.txt: `grep -xf <(sed 's/[^^]/[&]/g; s/\^/\\^/g' file2.txt) file1.txt`.

Comment: @ZiggyCrueltyfreeZeitgeister True, or use `-F`. Thank you for your remark.

Comment: This is why `fgrep` comes in handy. :-)